# Is there a way to delete something in Vim without moving it to a register?

Tags: vim

Often I want to delete something in Vim without moving it to a register. Is there a method of doing this? I find that having to explicitly specify the register `"a` to be a little much sometimes.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're actually asking two related questions here:

1. You want to delete text without it appearing in any registers
2. You want to be able to specify a default register other than `"`

The first one can be done, just use the `_` register, which is called the "black hole" register, instead of something like the `a` register.  For example: `"_dd`

The second one can't be done, as far as I know.

See [`:help registers`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#registers).

Comment: That still adds two more characters to the repeated task, I wanted to change the default register to _ so I shave two keystrokes off of a delete-paste cycle.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: You don't need to specify a register for a delete-paste cycle. Both operations use the default register (") by default.

Comment: Right, but I don't want the delete to clobber what is in the default register because I want to paste it without specifying a non-default register for the paste, or the delete.

Comment: Got it. In that case, and as Heptite wrote, I don't see a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do something like this:

```
nnoremap d "_d
vnoremap d "_d
```

But I wouldn't recommend it: Vim's default should stay the way they are.

Instead of `"_d`, I use these mappings to delete into the black hole register:

```
nnoremap <leader>d "_d
vnoremap <leader>d "_d
```

That's only shorter by one key but it's better than overwriting a Vim default.

I use this mapping when I need to paste something several times:

```
vnoremap <leader>p "_dP
```

Which goes like this:

```
10 yank something
20 select something else
30 paste over it
40 GOTO 20
```